# Different project settings for admins in Django

Tags: django, django-settings

I've just started to learn django. I'd like to know if it's possible to have different settings for certain users like admins with the default auth system.

For example I'd like to have **DEBUG = True** if the user is super user and **DEBUG = False** if not. Is it possible somehow?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: The recommended way to handle this is via [`Error Reporting`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#error-reporting)

Comment: @karthikr Thank you! What about Debug toolbar? If I have it in the INSTALLED_APPS all users will see it right? How would you show it only for admins?

Comment: I would not show it in production environments at all. The idea behind having various environments is, the application is well tested before it makes it production, and if any issues, should be resolved in dev, or integration /staging environments before they make it to production. I would _not_ make djdt an installed_app in production.